# Highstock change display format on y-axis when changing comparer

Tags: highcharts

Hi I'm using the following example:

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/members/axis-setcompare/

How do I a change format of the values on the y-axis. For example when I choose percentage i want the values to be displayed as +25%. I now how to initially set up this up but how do I change it with Jquery script.

```
formatter: function () {
return (this.value > 0 ? '+' : '') + this.value + '%';
}
```

/S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. Just use

```
chart.options.yAxis[0].labels.format = '{value} %';
```

to display label as percentage

Answer (score 0):

If you use formatter in the tooltip, you should have this.y instead of this.value.

```
     formatter: function() {
return (this.y > 0 ? '+' : '') + this.y;
                }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6neGD/1/

Comment: I solved it. Just use chart.options.yAxis[0].labels.format = '{value} %'; to display as percentage